# rbind.fill based on common pattern R

Tags: r

I have a lot of text files in R that are written in the following format:

```
building_000000.txt
building_window_roof_000123.txt
building_window_roof_000126.txt
...
```

which I have listed using this command

```
files_list <- list.files(pattern="txt")
```

What I wanted to do is to bind all files (dataframes) which have this pattern "building_roof_window_\\\\\d+" into a single .txt file by using mget(ls). I also wanted to use "rbind.fill" because not all dataframes have the same number of columns. So this is what I tried to do:

```
building_roof_window <- do.call("rbind.fill", mget(ls(pattern="^building[_]roof[_]window[_]\\\\\\d+")))
```

But the result is an empty dataframe. 
What am I missing? Is it perhaps due to the sloppy use of regex?

Comment: You don't need a very specific regex. Does `files_list` have all the files that you want?

Comment: It does. But there are a lot of other .txt files that I don't need right now.

Comment: I see. How about this? `list.files(pattern= 'building_roof_window_\\d+.*\\.txt$')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main task is to select filenames using correct regex. We can use the regex as below :

```
files_list  <- list.files(pattern= 'building_roof_window_\\d+.*\\.txt$')
building_roof_window <- do.call(plyr::rbind.fill, mget(files_list))
```

Comment: Although I get this error after running the do.call command: "Error: value for ‘building_window_000085.txt’ not found"
Must I create a list with the data frames first in order to bind them?

Comment: Try `files_list  <- list.files(pattern= 'building_roof_window_\\d+.*\\.txt$', full.names = TRUE)`

Comment: Nope. Same problem unfortunately

Comment: I am not sure then. Do you have file named `building_window_000085.txt` in your directory?

Comment: Yes, there is such a file in my directory

Comment: How many files do you have in `files_list` ? Can you see what exactly is different about `building_window_000085.txt` ?